# what's wrong in this Nsarray definition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsarray

I want to initialize an array of nsstrings I use the following code

```
@interface Modalities : UITableViewController {

    NSArray * Modalities ;

    NSArray* SelectedOnes ;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray * Modalities ;

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    Modalities = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  @"XA",
                  @"CT",
                  @"RF",
                  @"PR",
                  @"US",
                  @"OT",
                  @"SR",
                  @"MG",
                  @"MR",
                  @"NM",              
                  @"CR" , nil];
}
```

it raise

> error: expected unqualified-id before
>   '=' token

any suggestion to solve that

Comment: I think there is a confusion with the name of your class 'Modalities' and the name of your variable 'Modalities' , rename it as 'modalities'

Comment: And don't forget to retain array you create otherwise your app will crash trying to access Modalities outside of the viewDidLoad method:

Comment: Note that it is possible to have an ivar with the same name of a class. Ivar names and class names are in separate name spaces: http://objectivistc.tumblr.com/post/3340816080/name-spaces-in-objective-c — @Vladimir’s comment would’ve fixed your issue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the name of the Class for your field, this will cause a collision.

Change names of the field to

```
NSArray * modalities;
```

and then:

```
modalities = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              @"XA",
              @"CT",
              @"RF",
              @"PR",
              @"US",
              @"OT",
              @"SR",
              @"MG",
              @"MR",
              @"NM",              
              @"CR" , nil];
```